# how to redirect if logged_in is false in context else let proceed to page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I am working on a simple ReactJS application. I wanted to add authentication to my page so i opted context for my simpler requirements. I have a context variable which is false by default and when someone inputs correct username password, I set it to true. This is working till now. But my pages are still publicly accessible so I figured out I need to add redirection logic using HOC. But I am not able to understand how HOC can be implemented for this task.

Context.js

```
    import React from 'react';
     
    export const AppContext = React.createContext(false);
```

Login.js

```
    //other imports here
    import { AppContext } from '../context';

    export function LoginPage() {
      //component local state to track username password etc here
      let { loggedIn, toggleLoggedIn } = useContext(AppContext);

      const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      //some irrelevant stuff here
      fetch("/accounts/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'username': user,
          'password': password
        })})
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.ok) {
          toggleLoggedIn(true);
        }
      else {
        //some irrelevant stuff here
        }....
```

App.js

```
    //other components imports here
    import { AppContext } from './context';

    function App() {
      const [loggedIn, toggleLoggedIn] = useState(false);
      return (
        <div className="app">
          <Header className="app-header"/>
          <div className="links">
            <NavLink activeClassName="selected" exact className="link" to="/">Home page</NavLink>
            <NavLink activeClassName="selected" exact className="link" to="/open_alerts/">Open Alerts</NavLink>
            <NavLink activeClassName="selected" exact className="link" to="/backend_ops/">Backend operations</NavLink>
          </div>

          <AppContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, toggleLoggedIn}}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/login/">
                <div>
                  <LoginPage />
                </div>
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <div className="charts new-line-block">
                  <div className="split left">
                    <AlertsChart />
                  </div>
                  <div className="split right">
                    <RegionCharts />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/open_alerts/">
                <div className="alerts-table new-line-block">
                  <br></br>
                  <AlertsTable />
                </div>
              </Route>
              ...so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return routes based on logged in state:

```
  protectedRoute() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route exact path="/">
          <div className="charts new-line-block">
            <div className="split left">
              <AlertsChart />
            </div>
            <div className="split right">
              <RegionCharts />
            </div>
          </div>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
        </Route>
        .... ....
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
```

Then finally

```
{loggedIn ? (
         protectedRoute()
        ) : (
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Redirect to="/login" />
          </Switch>
        )}
```

Comment: I have a lot of components and 4 routes. Do I need to put all my routes and components in it into another component from App.js. Right? Thanks for yourhelp

Comment: Yes, whatever will be accessible to user after logging in needs to be in protectedRoutes

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I am new to JS and ReactJS. Can you elaborate the significance of using () to wrap protectedRoute() and <Switch> element. Is it just to group the elements? Plus,  protectedRoute() is a functional component then why it is not written as element but as function invocation?

Comment: protected route is a function indeed which returns the protected routes. Also it's not necessary to wrap `protectedRoute()` in `()`